# Simple Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Here is a C code which creates a simple linked list with three nodes. Afterward a function called `printList` traverses the created list and prints the data of each node.

```
    // A simple C program for traversal of a linked list
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };

    // This function prints contents of linked list starting from
    // the given node
    void printList(struct node *n)
    {
        while (n != NULL)
        {
            printf(" %d ", n->data);
            n = n->next;
        }
    }

int main()
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* second = NULL;
    struct node* third = NULL;

// allocate 3 nodes in the heap
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 1; //assign data in first node
    head->next = second; // Link first node with second

    second->data = 2; //assign data to second node
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3; //assign data to third node
    third->next = NULL;

    printList(head);
    printList(head); //question

    return 0;
}
```

Resource: http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/

My question is that, since the input argument of function `printList` is a pointer of type node, the value of the pointer seems to be changed after the function call. In other words, after calling `printList(head)`, it is reasonable to me that the pointer `head` must now point to a `NULL` value, therefore the second call to `printList` should print some irrelevant values. However, I am obviously wrong, since the output of this program is 1 2 3 1 2 3.

Could you please shed some light on this?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: When you pass arguments to a function, they are passed *by value*. That means the value is copied, and the function only modify the copy. The original variable will still keep its value.

Comment: This has been asked 100s of times. What is the output of this program: `void Foo(bar) {bar = 4;} int main() {int x = 0; Foo(x); printf("%d\n", x);}` ?

Comment: P.S. -> do not cast the result of your memory allocations.

Answer (score 2):

C passes parameters by value. That means that the value of the variable passed to a function is copied into a new variable which is local to the function. No matter how much you change the local variable inside the function, it will never change the value of the variable passed to the function.

In other words: `n` inside the function is **not** the same as `head` in `main`. The local variable `n` is just initialized to the same value as `head`

Answer (score 1):

Variables are passed by value; this is also true for a variable whose value is a pointer:

Suppose variable `head` of type `struct node*` points to a node, let's say a node at address `0x12345`.
When you call `printList(head)`, whereas the signature of this function is `void printList(struct node *n)`, then the *value* of `head` is copied to the *value* of `n`; Hence, variable `n` and variable `head`, though being different variables,  will have the value `0x12345`. If `printList` then changes the value of `n`, e.g. by statement `n = n->next`, then only the value of variable `n` is changed; variable `head` will still have the value `0x12345`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you so much, you made it really clear for me. Now I understand that why I was being so stupid and didn't get that sooner.